# Mapstruct Mapper with @ConfigProperty in JEE

Tags: java, mapstruct, java-ee-8

Hello good people of StackOverflow :)

I have implemented an Entity-DTO Mapper. In this Objects, I have some DateTime fields, in which I want to concat the TimeZone, which is a Configurable Property (as a deltaspike Property, or an application property in the respective .yml file).

I have converted my interface to an abstract class, yet still I cannot use the timezone property.

My code:

```
public abstract class DeclarationMapperToDomain {

@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "DECLARATION_TIMEZONE")
String timezone;

@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
@Mapping(source = "acceptanceDate",target = "acceptanceDateTime.dateTimeString.value", dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
abstract public Declaration declarationTransformerToDomain(DeclarationUI declarationUI);



 @AfterMapping
    void setDeclarationToDomain(@MappingTarget Declaration declaration, DeclarationUI declarationUI) {

        if(declaration.getAcceptanceDateTime() != null && declaration.getAcceptanceDateTime().getDateTimeString() != null) {
            declaration.getAcceptanceDateTime().getDateTimeString().setValue(declaration.getAcceptanceDateTime().getDateTimeString().getValue().concat(timezone));
        }
```

The problem is that the timezone property keeps on showing as null, when it shouldn't (I have set it to +01).

EDIT: Even if I am trying to Inject a Bean into the mapper, it is not properly injected.

ie

```
 @Inject
    EuUserPreferencesBean userPreferencesBean;
```

is always null.

Comment: How are you getting the mapper? I mean, `MapStruct` processor generates a subclass of `DeclarationMapperToDomain`, do you get it through injection too?

Comment: I figured a way around it, by passing in @Context the Timezone, as a parameter. Not sure if it's the ideal way to do it though.